# How to exclude row of Table1 if it appears in joined Table2?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables joined `orders` (id) and `order_status` (id, order_id, status_id).

I want to return only the orders that doesn't have a given `status_id`, I've tried:

```sql
SELECT order_id FROM orders
INNER JOIN  order_status 
ON orders.id = order_status.order_id 
WHERE order_status.status_id != 1
```

But it doesn't work because it still get some orders that have `status_id = 2` and that given order that have `status_id = 2` is the same that have `status_id = 1`, so in the end I'm still returning orders that are `status_id = 1`.

What I want is, if the given order have `order_status.status_id = 1`, it just ignore all the other rows of the same order id.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT o.order_id 
FROM orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM order_status s
  WHERE s.order_id = o.id AND s.status_id = 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's excatly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`. For example:

```
select *
from orders o
where not exists (select 1 from order_status s
                  where s.order_id = o.id ans s.status_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use it verbally almost, not necessarily the most efficient. Not tested but the idea is "select from the tables where not exists a record on order_status where status_id is not null".

```js
SELECT 
  order_id 
FROM 
  orders
  LEFT JOIN order_status ON orders.id = order_status.order_id 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_status WHERE order_id = orders.id AND status_id != null)
```